# @ScriptVariable resourceResolver vs @SlingObject resourceResolver

Tags: aem, sling-models

Can anyone explain to me the difference between calling `resourceResolver` by annotating `@ScriptVariable` and by annotating `@SlingObject`? In what context do they behave differently?

Answer (score 3):

The key difference is in the way the object is retrieved. `@ScriptVariable` and `@SlingObject` are [*injector-specific annotations*](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html#injector-specific-annotations). This means that you can use them to instruct Sling Models to use a particular [injector](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html#custom-injectors).

The injector that recognises the `@ScriptVariable` annotation can inject objects available as [Scripting Variables](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SLING/Scripting+variables). In case ot the `resourceResolver`, it should be the one associated with the request. *Same as `slingRequest.getResourceResolver()`*.

[Looking at the code](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-models-impl/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/models/impl/injectors/SlingObjectInjector.java#L74), the injector that kicks in on fields annotated with `@SlingObject` is a bit more interesting in that it will inspect the adaptable (from which your Sling Model is being adapted) and obtain the resolver accordingly:

- If the adaptable is a `Resource`, it'll return `resource.getResourceResolver()`, i.e. the resolver originally used to load the resource. This may be quite aribtrary.
- If the adaptable is a `SlingHttpServletRequest`, it'll return `request.getResourceResolver()`, i.e. the resolver instantiated by Sling in association with the request and the session of the user issuing the request.
- If the adaptable itself is a `ResourceResolver`, it will be returned directly.

In some cases, the difference between the three will be negligible, but sometimes it will be important which resolver you choose. If your model is, for example, supposed to be used outside the scope of a request (imagine it's instantiated by an OSGi service that runs on a schedule and there's no incoming request), you'll be better off using `resource` or `resourceResolver` as an adaptable.